# Tensorflow - run() and eval() print 'b' before constants

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow, so I'm following some tutorials. When I print variables or constants with eval() or run() it always prints a "b" before the value of the variable, e.g. variable = 'a', prints " b'a' ".

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    node1 = tf.constant("a")
    node2 = tf.constant("b")

    with tf.Session():
        print("%r %r"%(node1.eval(), node2.eval()))
```

result : b'a' b'b'.

I tried with different editors but the problem remains, does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, it might be related to some editor byte string representation.

Comment: it's a Python 3 thing, strings now have two types, bytes and unicode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of encoding. Try to decode as follows: `.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

in Python 3 change your print line by adding ".decode() like below and should work:

```
print("%r %r"%(node1.eval().decode(), node2.eval().decode()))
```